# DOM is changed but React State is not?

Tags: reactjs, dom

I have been trying to research this but I only find questions regarding why the DOM does not change when state does, but my problem is the opposite. For some reason, DOM changes the value when state is not (and it should not be changed).

I have a todo list in React where the user can edit and delete their list items. The user can edit three fields: "todo", "details" and "comment". When the user edits "comment" (the problem is only with comment for some reason) the item is updated as it should. But if I then delete an item above it (not happening if deleting below it), the item that was edited still have the comment, but the comment is also copied to the item below it in the DOM. In React state the below comment says null as it should.

For example, if we have this array of items:

```
items: [
                {
                    todo: "One",
                    details: "One",
                    comment: null,
                    id: 1
                },
                {
                    todo: "Two",
                    details: "Two",
                    comment: null,
                    id: 2
                },
                {
                    todo: "Three",
                    details: "Three",
                    comment: null,
                    id: 3
                },
                {
                    todo: "Four",
                    details: "Four",
                    comment: null,
                    id: 4
                }
            ],
```

If I (using the functions that I pasted below) add the string `"test"` to `"comment"` for `id 2`, and then deleting `id 1`, this will in DOM make it look like `id 2` and `id 3` has `comment: "test"`, but in state it says that only `id 2` have `"test"` and `id 3` has `comment: null` as it should. So state is correct but the DOM shows it wrong.

Any idea what might be happening here?

Here is the code, the example array can be used as the "items" array:

```
export class TodoList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items: [],
            deletedItems: [],
        }
    }

    editItem = (event) => {
        const column = event.target.name //what should be saved (can be "todo", "details" or "comment")
        const id = event.target.id //ID of the listItem
        const text = event.target.value //The text to be saved
        const editedItems = this.state.items
        //Look into state, find same ID and replace with the updated text
        let updateItems = editedItems.map(el => {
            if (el.id == id) {
                return Object.assign({}, el, { [column]: text })
            } 
            return el
        });
        this.setState({ items: updateItems })
      }

    deleteItem = (event) => {
        const id = event.target.id
        const removedItem = this.state.items.filter(el => el.id == id);  //Get the deleted item
        const listWithoutItem = this.state.items.filter(el => el.id != id); //Create new list without the deleted item
        const del = this.state.deletedItems.concat(removedItem); //Add removedItem to deletedItems array:
        this.setState({
            items: listWithoutItem, //set state for new array without the deleted item.
            deletedItems: del //set state for the item that should be deleted, will be added to an archive later on.
        })
    }


    render() {
        let items = "No actions"
        if (this.state.items.length > 0) {
            items = this.state.items.map((item) => {
                return <tr id={item.id}>
                    <td><TextareaAutosize onChange={this.editItem} className="tdStyle" name="todo" id={item.id} value={item.todo} /></td>
                    <td><TextareaAutosize onChange={this.editItem} className="tdStyle" name="details" id={item.id} value={item.details} /></td>
                    <td><TextareaAutosize onChange={this.editItem} className="tdStyle" name="comment" id={item.id} value={item.comment} /></td>
                    <td><img className="removeBtn" src={remove} id={item.id} onClick={this.deleteItem} /></td>
                </tr>
            });
        }
        return (
            <>
                <div className="container">
                        <table className="itemsTable">
                            <tr className="trStyleLine">
                                <th className="thpadding">Todo</th>
                                <th className="thpadding">Details</th>
                                <th className="thpadding">Comment</th>
                                <th className="thpadding">Delete</th>
                            </tr>
                            {items}
                        </table>
                </div>
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: change `<tr id={item.id}>` to `<tr key={item.id}>`. You can read more at https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/rendering-lists

Comment: working example at https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-herschel-myu855?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Works perfect. If you add it as an answer I can mark it as accepted. Thank you so much and for the explanation link